# How to make the SOAP request

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am making a SOAP request in Android. What exactly I want to achieve is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:GeneratePin>

         <tem:sEmail>xyz@abc.com</tem:sEmail>

         <tem:sFlage>true</tem:sFlage>
      </tem:GeneratePin>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

but I am getting:

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:c="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding" xmlns:v="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
<tem:GeneratePin xmlns="http://www.tempuri.org/">
<tem:sEmail>abc@xyz.com</tem:sEmail>
<tem:sFlage>true</tem:sFlage>
</tem:GeneratePin>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

I am using the following code:

```
static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/GeneratePin";
    static String namespace = "http://www.tempuri.org/";
    private static String url = "xyz";

    static SoapObject request = null;
    static SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope;
    static HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport;

    // MethodName variable is define for which webservice function will call
    public static String getPin(String MethodName) {

        try {
            request = new SoapObject(namespace, "tem:GeneratePin");

            /*
             * PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo(); pi.setName("sEmail");
             * pi.setValue("rishabh@vervesys.local"); request.addProperty(pi);
             * 
             * PropertyInfo pi1 = new PropertyInfo(); pi1.setName("sFlage");
             * pi1.setValue("true"); request.addProperty(pi1);
             */

            request.addProperty("tem:sEmail", "abc@xyz.com");
            request.addProperty("tem:sFlage", "true");

            System.out.println("request is : == " + request);
            envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.implicitTypes = true;
            envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
            envelope.encodingStyle = "utf-8";
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            /*
             * MarshalDouble marshaldDouble = new MarshalDouble();
             * marshaldDouble.register(envelope);
             */

            androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            System.out
                    .println("ONE!@#$%^& " + androidHttpTransport.requestDump);
            /*
             * androidHttpTransport
             * .setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
             */
            final SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope
                    .getResponse();
            Log.i("Webservice Output", response.toString());
            return response.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Are you using the KSOAP library?

Comment: yes..do u have any other library ?

Comment: No, I use KSOAP as well. Version 3 though. Never had this problem. :/

Comment: I just want soap as prefix instead of v. You can try out my code to see the problem.

Comment: Yes, I understand. The tags are different. But that never seemed to create a problem for me. If you look around the web, you will notice that everyone has the tag `<v>`. *just saying*

Comment: ya...bt in my case its creating a huge problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like KSoap has a hardcoded value for the namespace in `SoapEnvelope`:

https://github.com/karlmdavis/ksoap2-android/blob/master/ksoap2-base/src/main/java/org/ksoap2/SoapEnvelope.java#L182

```
/**
* Writes the complete envelope including header and body elements to the
* given XML writer.
*/
    public void write(XmlSerializer writer) throws IOException {
        writer.setPrefix("i", xsi);
        writer.setPrefix("d", xsd);
        writer.setPrefix("c", enc);
        writer.setPrefix("v", env);
        writer.startTag(env, "Envelope");
        writer.startTag(env, "Header");
        writeHeader(writer);
        writer.endTag(env, "Header");
        writer.startTag(env, "Body");
        writeBody(writer);
        writer.endTag(env, "Body");
        writer.endTag(env, "Envelope");
    }
```

The `SoapSerializationEnvelope` you're creating here:

```
envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
```

…is a subclass of `SoapEnvelope`. So, to change the behaviour, you need to subclass `SoapSerializationEnvelope` like so:

```
public class CustomSoapSerializationEnvelope extends SoapSerializationEnvelope {

    @Override
    public void write(XmlSerializer writer) throws IOException {
        writer.setPrefix("i", xsi);
        writer.setPrefix("d", xsd);
        writer.setPrefix("c", enc);
        writer.setPrefix("soap", env); // <-- changed line
        writer.startTag(env, "Envelope");
        writer.startTag(env, "Header");
        writeHeader(writer);
        writer.endTag(env, "Header");
        writer.startTag(env, "Body");
        writeBody(writer);
        writer.endTag(env, "Body");
        writer.endTag(env, "Envelope");
    }
}
```

Then, replace the above line with:

```
envelope = new CustomSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
```

Comment: You are a savior. It works...!!! I had to make few more changes to make it work. Thank You.