# How to create proper soap envelope (request xml) in code while using KSoap2?

Tags: android, soap, wsdl, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

This is the soap request as obtained from SoapUi by feeding the wsdl.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:typ="http://wsclient.xyz.com/types/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <typ:loginserviceElement>
         <typ:username>test.test</typ:username>
         <typ:password>test123</typ:password>
      </typ:loginserviceElement>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But the android code dumped (from logcat) the request as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding= "UTF-8" ?>
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <v:Header />
    <v:Body>
        <n0:loginservice xmlns:n0="http://wsclient.xyz.com//">
            <username>test.test</username>
            <password>test1234</password>
        </n0:loginservice>
    </v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

***My question is- Is both the xml request are same or should work interchangeably? If not how can I customize the request to match the one I get from SoapUi?***

As mentioned in the reposnce I am getting:

***SoapFault - faultcode: 'env:Client' faultstring: 'Caught exception while handling request: unrecognized operation: {http://wsclient.xyz.com//}loginservice' faultactor: 'null' detail: null***

Response from SoapUi (what I am trying to achive in anddroid code):

```
  <env:Body>
      <ns0:loginserviceResponseElement>
         <ns0:result>
            <ns0:logintoken>181210281021ahash</ns0:logintoken>
            <ns0:hrmsid>0000002</ns0:hrmsid>
         </ns0:result>
      </ns0:loginserviceResponseElement>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I have tried many answer as found on SO and other tutorials with out success.

***I would be grateful if a reference to good link can be provided that some how clearly describes the different tags like v:Envelope or soapenv:Envelope, n0:loginservice or typ:loginserviceElement or type:loginserviceElement  etc***

Below is the android code for reference:

```
public class SoapRequests {

    private static final boolean DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE = true;    
    private static final String MAIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://abc.xyz.com/WSClient/WSServiceSoapHttpPort";
    private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://wsclient.xyz.com//";
    private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://wsclient.xyz.com//loginservice";
    private static String SESSION_ID;

    private final void testHttpResponse(HttpTransportSE ht) {
        ht.debug = DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE;
        if (DEBUG_SOAP_REQUEST_RESPONSE) {
            Log.v("SOAP RETURN", "Request XML:\n" + ht.requestDump);
            Log.v("SOAP RETURN", "\n\n\nResponse XML:\n" + ht.responseDump);
        }
    }

    public User getUserData(String name, String pwd){       
         User user = null;
         String methodname = "loginservice";

         SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodname);         

         PropertyInfo userName =new PropertyInfo();
         userName.setName("username");
         userName.setValue(name);
         userName.setType(String.class);
         request.addProperty(userName);

         PropertyInfo password =new PropertyInfo();
         password.setName("password");
         password.setValue(pwd);
         password.setType(String.class);
         request.addProperty(password);

         SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = getSoapSerializationEnvelope(request);
         HttpTransportSE ht = getHttpTransportSE();

         try {
             ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
             testHttpResponse(ht);
             SoapPrimitive resultsString = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
             String data = resultsString.toString();
             Log.v("***********RESPONSE*******************", data);

         } catch (SocketTimeoutException t) {
             t.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException i) {
             i.printStackTrace();
         } catch (Exception q) {
             q.printStackTrace();
         }

         // some code to set user data
         ....
         return user;

    }

    private SoapSerializationEnvelope getSoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapObject request) {
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = false;
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.setAddAdornments(false);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        return envelope;
    }

    private final HttpTransportSE getHttpTransportSE() {
        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(Proxy.NO_PROXY,MAIN_REQUEST_URL,60000);
        ht.debug = true;
        ht.setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?>");
        return ht;
    }
}
```

EDIT: RESPONSE from android code:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns0="http://wsclient.xyz.com/types/">
    <env:Body>
    <env:Fault>
        <faultcode>env:Client</faultcode>
        <faultstring>Caught exception while handling request: unrecognized operation: {http://wsclient.hrms.com//}loginservice</faultstring>
    </env:Fault>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well finally I got it working after some more research and got the answers to the questions.

1) Though SoapUi genearted `<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="...." ....>` type response xml and android code using Ksoap2 library genearted `<v:Envelope xmlns:i="..." ...>` type response xml have different looking tags, it is not significant in getting errors. Both are similar.

As mentioned on the answer to [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166499/how-to-make-the-soap-request?rq=1), ksoap has  hardcoded values for the namespace in SoapEnvelope.

2) The unrecognized operation exception was due to issue in the MAIN_REQUEST_URL and NAMESPACE. Knowing the proper value of url, namespace and the soap_action is bit tricky, at least for a beginner in this space.

The values of these fields can be set by looking at the request/response xml, wsdl and [this nice pictorial example.](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/)

In my case, I had to change

```
MAIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://abc.xyz.com/WSClient/WSServiceSoapHttpPort";
NAMESPACE = "http://wsclient.xyz.com//";
SOAP_ACTION = "http://wsclient.xyz.com//loginservice";
```

to

```
MAIN_REQUEST_URL = "http://abc.xyz.com/WSClient/WSServiceSoapHttpPort?WSDL";
NAMESPACE = "http://wsclient.xyz.com/types/";
SOAP_ACTION = "http://wsclient.xyz.com//loginservice";
```

and also I had to change:

```
String methodname = "loginservice";
```

to

```
String methodname = "loginserviceElement";
```

as the request/response xml has this ( typ:loginserviceElement ) tag wrapping the properties/parameters.

Comment: many thanks to the author of http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/how-to-call-web-service-in-android-using-soap/. Before this i had gone through several tutorials/example /question-answers, but the proper value for namespace, url etc were not clear.