# how to create Soap request with token and envelope

Tags: android, soap, soap-client, android-ksoap2

I am trying to create soap request in android but not able to get how to generate this.

I have gone through following URL:-
   [url-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711231/how-to-create-proper-soap-envelope-request-xml-in-code-while-using-ksoap2)
   [url-2](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/consuming-web-services-with-ksoap--mobile-21242)

but not able to understand how to create soap request like this.

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:stal="http://ws.soapwebserv.com/Info">
  <soapenv:Header>
 <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis- open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
 <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-30" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
 <wsse:Username>alias101@soapwebserv.com</wsse:Username>
  <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">somesecurepassword</wsse:Password>
 </wsse:UsernameToken>
 </wsse:Security>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
  <stal:InfoRequest>
 <token>randomtokenrandomtoken</token>
 </stal:InfoRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

please help me out guys... I am new to Soap. :(

Comment: used `ksoap library` for that. it's very easy.

Comment: I have ksoap library but dont know how to create request @M D

Comment: you have to generate `java` code from `wsdl` format. you can achieve from [this site](http://www.wsdl2code.com/pages/home.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

simple way is to copy the entire soapenvelope  in raw folder as xml file  and pass your username ,password and token with help of pattern matching . Now you have the entire request in the form of string pass the request   to httppost method.let me know that helps your issue.